# Unable to execute python for sublimetext

Tags: python

I just installed sublime text and when I select the build system as python, it doesn't work. The command prompt with pops up at the bottom of the frame says: "can't find '**main**' module in ' '".

Comment: Just to make sure, what have you tried to do to correct the error it's giving you?

Comment: Googling your error has given me [this page](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/cant-find---main---module-in/12468/3) as the first result, which explains what seems to be the exact problem you're having. Have you tried the stuff in that?

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps.

1. you need to SAVE your code file with the “.py” extension.
2. Then, on the ‘Tools/Build System’ menu, make sure your build system is set to either ‘auto’ or ‘Python’. If everything works fine, you are ready to go.

Otherwise, simply type " python " (without the quotes) in a cmd terminal to make sure python is in your path.